# Inserting Unicode to MSSQL via PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, unicode, arabic

I'm trying to insert Arabic language to mssql database. database column is set to nvarchar
Data is posted through PHP to a mssql stored procedure.

the problem is : data got inserted as `Þ‰ÞªÞ‡Þ°Þ‹Þ¦ÞŒÞª Þ‡Þ¨ÞÞ°ÞŒÞ¨Þ‡ÞªÞ‚Þ§ÞŠÞ° ÞŠÞ¯Þ‰Þ¬`

could any one please help me to get the correct data to be inserted without converting.

```
>  <?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');  include_once
> 'connect.php';
> 
>   sqlsrv_query ($conn,"set character_set_client='utf8'");  
>   sqlsrv_query ($conn,"set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
>   sqlsrv_query ($conn,"set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
>   
> 
> 
>    $tsql = 'Exec SP @NO=?,@Date=?,@IN=?,@creason=?';            
> $params = array($empno,$dutydate,$inDT,$outDT,$reason);
> 
>    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql,$params) ;
>   
>        $dataArray = array();
>        if ($stmt === false)       {           echo 'SQL Error';           print_r(sqlsrv_errors());       }       else        {
>           
>           
>           
>               $dataArray['error'] =array();
>               while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
>                   array_push($dataArray['error'],$row);
>               }
>               sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
>               
>               }    echo json_encode($dataArray);
> 
> ?>
```

Comment: Include some of your code that shows the problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

For the field to be able to store unicode characters, you have to use the type `nvarchar` (or other similar like `ntext`, `nchar`).

To insert the unicode characters in the database you have to send the text as unicode by using a parameter type like `nvarchar` / `SqlDbType.NVarChar`.

(For completeness: if you are creating SQL dynamically (against common advice), you put an `N` before a string literal to make it unicode. For example: `insert into table (name) values (N'Pavan').`)

Comment: $tsql = 'Exec SP @NO=?,@Date=?,@IN=?,@creason=?';         
   $params = array($empno,$dutydate,$inDT,$outDT,$reason);

   $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql,$params) ;

i want to send this ($reason) parameter in unicode. is it possible to do as you mentioned? like N'@Reason' ?